# How to unit test a component that depends on parameters from ActivatedRoute?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-testing

I am unit testing a component that is used to edit an object. The object has an unique `id` that is used in order to grab the specific object from an array of objects that are hosted in a service. The specific `id`is procured through a parameter that is passed via routing, specifically through the `ActivatedRoute` class.

The constructor is as follows:

```js
constructor(private _router:Router, private _curRoute:ActivatedRoute, private _session:Session) {}
    
ngOnInit() {
  this._curRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.userId = params['id'];
    this.userObj = this._session.allUsers.filter(user => user.id.toString() === this.userId.toString())[0];
```

I want to run basic unit tests on this component. However, I am not sure as to how I can inject the `id` parameter, and the component *needs* this parameter.

By the way: I already have a mock for the `Session` service, so no worries there.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to just use the `useValue` attribute and provide an Observable of the value you want to mock.

**RxJS < 6**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
...
{
  provide: ActivatedRoute,
  useValue: {
    params: Observable.of({id: 123})
  }
}
```

**RxJS >= 6**

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
...
{
  provide: ActivatedRoute,
  useValue: {
    params: of({id: 123})
  }
}
```

Comment: Observable.of does not exists for me!  :S

Comment: Import Observable from rxjs/Observable

Comment: This code makes this error in my project: `Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'ng:///DynamicTestModule/HomeContentComponent.ngfactory.js'.
at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:2605`

Comment: @MixerOID this is chrome eating bugs - put the test in a try-catch and you should see the error.

Comment: I know its 2 years later... but if you're getting the `Uncaught NetworkError` error that MixerOID posted, make sure you're using the right type of params. My issue was that my code was expecting `queryParams`, not `params`.

Comment: To avoid the generic `Uncaught NetworkError...`, you can also disable sourcemaps by running tests with `ng test --sourcemaps=false` - then you should see the real error causing the issue

Comment: {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            snapshot: {
              params: Observable.of({userName: 'testUser', emailValidationToken: 'token'})
            }
          }
        }

Comment: RxJs 6 `of` should be used alone. Also you'd likely use `RouterTestingModule` instead of this answer's code.

Comment: @BenRacicot this answer was given before RxJs 6 existed.  Also instead saying "do this instead" provide an answer that can be upvoted directly.

Comment: I would have not guessed that is the way to do it in a million years... Thanks Google...

Answer (score 45):

In angular 8+ there is the `RouterTestingModule`, which you can use in order to have access to the `ActivatedRoute` or `Router` of the component. Also you can pass routes to the `RouterTestingModule` and create spies for the requested methods of route.

For example in my component I have:

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')) this.editMode()
    this.titleService.setTitle(`${this.pageTitle} | ${TAB_SUFFIX}`)
}
```

And in my test I have:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ProductLinePageComponent ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents()
  }))

  beforeEach(() => {
    router = TestBed.get(Router)
    route = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute)
  })
```

and later in the 'it' section:

```
  it('should update', () => {
    const spyRoute = spyOn(route.snapshot.paramMap, 'get')
    spyRoute.and.returnValue('21')
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProductLinePageComponent)
    component = fixture.componentInstance
    fixture.detectChanges()
    expect(component).toBeTruthy()
    expect(component.pageTitle).toBe('Edit Product Line')
    expect(component.formTitle).toBe('Edit Product Line')
    // here you can test the functionality which is triggered by the snapshot
  })
```

In a similar way, I think you can test directly the `paramMap` via the `spyOnProperty` method of jasmine, by returning an observable or using rxjs marbles. It might save some time & also it does not require to maintain an extra mock class.
Hope that it is useful and it makes sense.

Comment: So much better than having to maintain an extra mock and you can easily set different parameters in tests. Thank you!

Comment: This helps. Do you know how to spy on different params:
    const dirName = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('dirName');
    const actionType = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('actionType');

On which of bot will spy spyOn(route.snapshot.paramMap, 'get') ? Can I specify key to listen ?

Comment: As I mention above, I think you could use spyOnProperty instead of spyOn, for example spyOnProperty(route.snapshot.paramMap.get, 'dirName'). If I haven't answered your question completely, don't hesitate to tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you , this was informative and helpful ☺

Comment: This works with Angular 6

Comment: This is the right way to do it!

Answer (score 20):

I have figured out how to do this!

Since `ActivatedRoute` is a service, a mock service for it can be established. Let's call this mock service `MockActivatedRoute`. We will extend `ActivatedRoute` in `MockActivatedRoute`, as follows:

```
class MockActivatedRoute extends ActivatedRoute {
    constructor() {
        super(null, null, null, null, null);
        this.params = Observable.of({id: "5"});
    }
```

The line `super(null, ....)` initializes the super class, which has four mandatory parameters. However, in this instance, we need nothing from any of these parameters, so we initialize them to `null` values. All we need is the value of `params` which is an `Observable<>`. Therefore, with `this.params`, we override the value of `params` and initialize it to be the `Observable<>` of the parameter on which the test subject is relying.

Then, as any other mock service, just initialize it and override the provider for the component.

*Good luck!*

Comment: I am facing this right now! However, I'm getting errors when I try to use `super` or `Observable`. Where do these come from?

Comment: `super()` is built in. `Observable` is from `rxjs/Observable` or just `rxjs` depending on your version.  You'd get it using `import {Observable} from 'rxjs'`.

Comment: You've accepted one answer and posted another... if this was Highlander (and there could only be one), which one did you "really" pick and why? That is, I think this essentially reduces to the same thing as zmanc's answer, which you accepted. Did you find additional value from setting up this [slightly] more complicated mock?

Answer (score 11):

Here is how I tested it in angular 2.0 latest...

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Data } from '@angular/router';
```

and in Providers section

```
{
  provide: ActivatedRoute,
  useValue: {
    data: {
      subscribe: (fn: (value: Data) => void) => fn({
        yourData: 'yolo'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the complete code for the providers section?

Comment: This is a complete unit test class.

https://plnkr.co/edit/UeCKnJ2sCCpLLQcWqEGX?p=catalogue

Comment: How do you test unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy

Comment: This will break in a real life usecase because you aren't returning a subscription and you won't be able to use call .unsubscribe() in ngOnDestroy.

Comment: data: Observable.of({yourData: 'yolo'}) would work though.

Comment: I agree with @Quovadisqc that you should NOT be mocking classes outside your program. This is a good solution when you replace the subscribe stuff with an Observable.of

Answer (score 9):

Just add a mock of the ActivatedRoute:

```
providers: [
  { provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: MockActivatedRoute }
]
```

...

```
class MockActivatedRoute {
  // here you can add your mock objects, like snapshot or parent or whatever
  // example:
  parent = {
    snapshot: {data: {title: 'myTitle ' } },
    routeConfig: { children: { filter: () => {} } }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ran into the same issue while creating test suites for a routing path as:

```
{
   path: 'edit/:property/:someId',
   component: YourComponent,
   resolve: {
       yourResolvedValue: YourResolver
   }
}
```

In the component, I initialized the passed property as:

```
ngOnInit(): void {    
   this.property = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.property;
   ...
}
```

When running the tests, if you do not pass a property value in your mock ActivatedRoute "useValue", then you will get undefined when detecting changes using "fixture.detectChanges()". This is because the mock values for ActivatedRoute does not contain the property params.property. Then, it is required for the mock useValue to have those params in order for the fixture to initialize the 'this.property' in the component. You can add it as:

```
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<YourComponent>;
  let component: YourComponent;
  let activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute; 

  beforeEach(done => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [YourComponent],
          imports: [ YourImportedModules ],
          providers: [
            YourRequiredServices,
            {
              provide: ActivatedRoute,
              useValue: {
                snapshot: {
                  params: {
                    property: 'yourProperty',
                    someId: someId
                  },
                  data: {
                    yourResolvedValue: { data: mockResolvedData() }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        })
          .compileComponents()
          .then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
            component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
            activatedRoute = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute);
            fixture.detectChanges();
            done();
          });
      });
```

The you can start testing as for example:

```
it('should ensure property param is yourProperty', async () => {
   expect(activatedRoute.snapshot.params.property).toEqual('yourProperty');
   ....
});
```

Now, lets say you would like to test a different property value, then you can update your mock ActivatedRoute as:

```
  it('should ensure property param is newProperty', async () => {
    activatedRoute.snapshot.params.property = 'newProperty';
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    activatedRoute = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(activatedRoute.snapshot.params.property).toEqual('newProperty');
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it's working, i just dont know why it is not working when i only put activatedRoute.snapshot and fixture.detect.. in the it . but when i copied your code its working

Comment: do you have any idea, why do i have to initialize again the fixture and component in it block even if it has already in the beforeeach?

Answer (score 4):

angular 11:
add this in your spec file

```
imports: [
   RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])
],
```

this help me out with just a single line, with other you need to mock provider

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the `beforeAll` function. Since `beforeAll` is called before all of your `beforeEach` functions, you can change your member variables before the component is compiled.

```js
describe('MyComponent', () => {

  let fakeActivatedRoute = {
    paramMap: of(convertToParamMap({ id: '123' })),
    queryParamMap: of(convertToParamMap({ query: 'active' }))};


  beforeEach(async() => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({

      providers: [
        ...
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: fakeActivatedRoute }],
      }).compileComponents();
    });
  });

  describe('id is present in route', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      fakeActivatedRoute.paramMap = 
        of(convertToParamMap({ id: '123' }));
      fakeActivatedRoute.queryParamMap = 
        of(convertToParamMap({ query: '' }));
    });

    it('should call service to look up id', () => {
      ...
    });
  });

  describe('id is not present in route', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      fakeActivatedRoute.paramMap = 
        of(convertToParamMap({ id: '' }));
      fakeActivatedRoute.queryParamMap = 
        of(convertToParamMap({ query: '' }));
    });

    it('should not call service to look up id', () => {
      ...
    });
  });

  describe('query is present in route', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      fakeActivatedRoute.paramMap = 
        of(convertToParamMap({ id: '123' }));
      fakeActivatedRoute.queryParamMap = 
        of(convertToParamMap({ query: 'inactive' }));
    });

    it('should call service to look up the inactive id', () => {
      ...
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You saved my day, thanks!  I have added `data` attribute also: ```typescript
const fakeActivatedRoute = {
    data: of({ app: 'note' }),
  };

```

Answer (score 3):

For some folks working on Angular > 5, **if Observable.of(); is not working then they can use just of() by importing import { of } from 'rxjs';**

Answer (score 1):

public 2023

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.bookId = +this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('bookId');

  this.getBook(this.bookId);
}
```

**for one parameter**

```
providers: [
   {
    provide: ActivatedRoute,
    useValue: {
      snapshot: {
        paramMap: {
          get: () => 1, // represents the bookId
        },
      },
    },
  },
],
```

**for two or more parameter**

If we only care about one paramater contained in paramMap, like in the example above, we can return this parameter directly from the get method: get: () => 1. If there are multiple parameters we care about we can use a switch statement instead:

```
  provide: ActivatedRoute,
  useValue: {
    snapshot: {
      paramMap: {
        get: (key: string) => {
          switch (key) {
            case 'bookId':
              return 2;
            case 'genre':
              return 'fiction'
              default:
              return ''
          }
        }
      },
    },
  },
},
```

**With activated route param observables**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.bookId = parseInt(params.bookId, 10)

    this.getBookById(this.bookId)
  })
}
```

We are still able to mock the router params but params will need to return an observable to allow our subscription to work. We can do this by using the RxJs of operator:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

...
{
  provide: ActivatedRoute,
  useValue: {
    params: of({
      bookId: 2,
    }),
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Added provider in the test class as:

```
{
  provide: ActivatedRoute,
  useValue: {
    paramMap: of({ get: v => { return { id: 123 }; } })
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All other answers so far only do provide the value for the route param. What if you want to test the route change trigger itself? You can provide the ActivatedRoute in your test with a Subject and its Observable, so you can trigger the route change with source.next().

Code under test:

```ts
    constructor(private readonly route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.routeParamSubscription = this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
        if (params['id']) {
          this.loadDetails(params['id']);
        }
      });
    }
```

Testing code:

```ts
    let routeChangeSource: BehaviorSubject<Params>;
    // In TestBed.configureTestingMethod
    ...
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            params: routeChangeSource.asObservable()
          }
        }
      ]
    ...
    it('loads data on route change', fakeAsync(() => {
      const spy = spyOn(component, 'loadDetails').and.callThrough();
      routeChangeSource.next({ id: 99 });
      tick();
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(99);
    }));
```

This tests the triggered action after the route change and makes sure it is activated.

Answer (score 0):

In this case if the parameter is being accessed by the `get` method of the `paramMap`

in the .ts:

```
this.id= this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

in the .spec.ts

```
providers: [
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            snapshot: {
              paramMap: {
                get() {
                  return '97dbf5d7';
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
```