# How to unit test a component that depends ActivatedRoute unsubscribe?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, components, observable, unsubscribe

I have a similar question as [How to unit test a component that depends on parameters from ActivatedRoute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356084/how-to-unit-test-a-component-that-depends-on-parameters-from-activatedroute)

Basically I'm unit testing a component which has `ActivatedRoute` dependency. I also have `unsubscribe` method in my component:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
```

}

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined
```

I have tried mocking ActiveRoot as below, but subscription is `void` so I'm not sure how to test this!

```
let mockActivatedRoute = {
data: {
  subscribe: (fn: (value: Data) => void) => fn({
    yourData: 'yolo'
  })
},
params: {
  next: Observable.of([0]),
  subscribe: () => { Observable.of([]); }
}
```

};

Comment: subscribe is not a function, you can't mock it as void

Comment: Please post the main part of the test.